# What does "grows along the block dimension to accommodate its content" from MDN mean?

Tags: html, css, display

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) says:

> By default, a block level element's content fills the available inline space of the parent element containing it and grows along the block dimension to accommodate its content.

But I don't know what they mean by "grows along the block dimension to accommodate its content".

What grows along the block dimension and what is the block dimension and what is the content?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size#:~:text=The%20block%2Dsize%20CSS%20property,the%20value%20of%20writing%2Dmode%20.

Content refers to any children in the container.

Comment: @JoshuaLewis That answers one part of it.

Comment: The link should explain most of it. It basically just means if a container's writing mode is horizontal, it will expand widthwise to fit its content. Think of a stock standard horizontal div. The more text you input, the more the div will grow horizontally. This is its "content" and it is growing along the block dimension (horizontal, left to right) to accomodate it.

Comment: @JoshuaLewis - Close, but no cigar. The block dimension means "vertically" in a horizontal writing mode.